# Почему не работает свойство align-content: space-between;?

Tags: html, css3, flexbox

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .cout-brand-block {
    height: auto;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
   }
  .brand-block-1,
  .brand-block-2,
  .brand-block-3,
  .brand-block-4 {
  }
}

 /*почему блоки  brand-block не получают вертикальны отступ между друг другом?/*
```

Comment: почему не получают?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что нужно задать `display: flex;`  и фиксированную высоту:

```css
.cout-brand-block {
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

  .brand-block-1,
  .brand-block-2,
  .brand-block-3,
  .brand-block-4 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<div class="cout-brand-block">
  <div class="brand-block-1">
    1
  </div>
  
  <div class="brand-block-2">
    2
  </div>
  
  <div class="brand-block-3">
    3
  </div>
  
  <div class="brand-block-4">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S:** `align-content: space-between;` только задает положение блоков, но не отступы! Чтобы задать отступы для блоков, используйте `margin` (внешние отступы) или `padding` (внутренние отступы). Т.е. например:

```
  .brand-block-1,
  .brand-block-2,
  .brand-block-3,
  .brand-block-4 {
    margin: 50px;
  }
```

Comment: В основном файле и стоит фиксированая высота, но в медиа запросе нужна свободная высота, что бы внутренние елементы растягивали контейнер...

Comment: `height: auto` высота будет равна высоте всех блоков внутри (с отступами), чтобы она начала растягиваться и появились отступы у блоков им нужно задавать эти отступы!!! Т.е. `.brand-block-1,
  .brand-block-2,
  .brand-block-3,
  .brand-block-4 {
  margin: Xpx Ypx; }`. А `align-content: space-between;` только задает положение блоков, но никак не отступы!

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось!)

Comment: @L1ght_time Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как принятый (зелёная галочка слева от ответа), если он вам помог.